# R: Apply function to every row of dataframe containing strings

Tags: r

Sorry for this, it's probably a duplicate but I'm having a bad time with the apply function. I would like to apply a function to every row of a dataset where the function will do an operation between two strings. Example:

(imagine a dataframe with two colums: t1 & t2)
"this is", "this is a test"
"my head will explode", "i like my head"

I have a function that takes two strings and returns the number of words in common something like:

```
commonwords <- function(s1,s2) {
  return (length(intersect(strsplit(s1,split=" ")[[1]],strsplit(s2,split=" ")[[1]])))
}
```

(Note I haven't pasted the function I just quick typed it to give you an indea so syntax could be wrong!)

I just need a way to apply that function to every row of the dataframe returning a new column with the number of words in common.
This can then be extended to any other operations between two strings.

Thanks a lot for the help I think this will be quick :)

Luis.

Comment: You can check `?apply` To loop over rows, MARGIN=1 is used. i.e. using your function `apply(df1, 1, function(x) commonwords(x[1],x[2]))`

Comment: Thank you I was missing the syntax about how to pass the parameters to the custom function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First please , take the time to create a reproducible example and clean code.

Since you want to apply an operation between 2 variables, you should use `mapply` here.

```
xx <- 
data.frame(S1=c( "this is","my head will explode"),
           S2=c("this is a test", "i like my head"))

 mapply(commonwords,xx[,'S1'],xx[,'S2'])
         this is my head will explode 
               2                    2
```

Where `commonwords` is:

```
commonwords <- function(s1,s2) {
  length(intersect(strsplit(s1,split=" ")[[1]],
                   strsplit(s2,split=" ")[[1]]))
}
```